# How to access CSS files in Rotativa PDF plugin over un-secure HTTPS connection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, rotativa

I have a ASP.NET MVC application, in which I have a functionality to download some data as a PDF. To achieve this, I am using **Rotativa** PDF plugin. I pass a view(.cshtml file) to this plugin and it converts that view into PDF. This view is a full-blown HTML file with  to couple of CSS files for styling.

The issue is, if I host this application as a **http://localhost**, then the generated PDF is able to download CSS files and apply the style in the output. But, if I host this application as a UN-SECURE host **https://localhost**, then the generated pdf, is not able to download these CSS files internally. I verified this finding by hosting it on SECURE host also, over there it worked.

Comment: When you talking about unsecure in https, is it self signed certificate ?

Comment: Any errors in logs? Maybe you're trying to access the filesystem?

Comment: Unclear and lacks any info even remotely close to [mcve], thus unanswerable as of now unless with a lucky guess.

Comment: Just confirm me that, all external linking have `https` in them. For example if your host is `https://localhost` then make sure your external linking files have `https` in it too like `<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`

Comment: Yes, the https here is self-signed or expired certificate and there are no external links for CSS and JS, all are internal links but they start with https.
Also I am not accession any file system. Its a very basic .html file with few internal CSS links